# Can strong magnetic fields exist in a large scale?

Tags: cosmology, magnetic-fields, astrophysics, astronomy

there. Can strong magnetic fields with strength about $1$ T to $10^{3}$ T exist in a large scale, e.g., about several light years?

I searched on Google Scholar, but I could not find related papers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The universe is vast and there is room for such things.

There are celestial bodies called magnetars. Their magnetic field reaches about $10^8 T$ on the surface.

Comment: But do magnetars' magnetic fields extend to several light years?

Comment: Thanks. I have considered magnetars. But as Kyle Kanos said, the strong magnetic field is on the surface. It should decay very soon as we leave the surface. Is it possible that a large scale of plasma rotating to create such large-scale strong magnetic field?